# How to move a QPlainTextEdit textbox in PyQt

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, pyqt6

I have tried using .move for a QPlainTextEdit textbox but it does not move in the GUI. What other options do I have?

```
from PyQt6.QtGui import *
from PyQt6.QtWidgets import *
from PyQt6.QtCore import *

class MainWindow(QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(MainWindow, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.setGeometry(700, 200, 600, 600)

        self.text = QPlainTextEdit(self)
        self.text.move(10,10)
        self.text.setReadOnly(True)
        l = QHBoxLayout()
        l.addWidget(self.text, 0)

app = QApplication([])
window = MainWindow()
sys.exit(app.exec())
```

However, the textbox just stays in its original position

Comment: Please provide a valid [mre]. Also, if you're using [layout managers](//doc.qt.io/qt-5/layout.html) (and you should), manually setting the geometry is almost always pointless: you should properly use spacers and stretch factors instead.

Comment: I'm not using layout managers, I am manually assigning positions to each textbox as I want them to align to a graph in the GUI. I have also edited my code to show my problem more accurately.

Comment: Your code does exactly what it's expected: the text edit is at 10 pixel from the top and left border of the window. Try increasing that amount and you'll see the difference. That said, as written, you should *not* use manual geometries, as it would most certainly result in unexpected behavior (including the inability to properly use the UI). If you don't know how to properly use layouts, I suggest you to do some practice with them using [Designer](//doc.qt.io/qt-6/designer-layouts.html) so that you can better understand how layouts work. Also, ensure that you carefully read the link above.